# ASP.NET Calling javascript functions in a Hangfire queue

Tags: javascript, asp.net, hangfire

In my asp.net application, I have a background queue task which is handled by Hangfire.

Within the job, I'm trying to call a javascript function which will update browser its current progress.

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, senderType, "UpdateProgressBar2", "UpdateProgressBar2(50,\"abc\")", true);
```

However, doing so gives me an error:

```
Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException' occurred in Newtonsoft.Json.dll
```

What did I do wrong?

Comment: Have you seen http://docs.hangfire.io/en/latest/background-processing/tracking-progress.html?

Comment: yes I did. I tried using SignalR but it's not working too well for me. Perhaps there is a simpler example out there?

Comment: If not signalr, then you'll have to poll into the web app via javascript. I don't see how you can originate push notifications from server .NET into client-side browser javascript without signalr. Just have a js function run every second that asks an e.g. WebAPI endpoint in your app how long the job has to go. You'll then need to glue that into your job somehow.